# SQL Server Connection from .net

Tags: .net, sql-server

I´m learning .net with SQL Server. I´ve installed visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008R2.

I do not have any problems working within the SQL Server Management Studio. I can work with databases.

I´m trying to make a connection to a database from .net, the following is the connection string

```
myconn.ConnectionString = 
                "Data Source=.\'Manuel-PC\'SQLINFMASTERIA;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
```

and I´ve got the following error on the line `mycommand.Connection = myconn;`

> "Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se
>   establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el
>   servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la
>   instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir
>   conexiones remotas. (provier:Named Pipes Provider, erro:40 - No se
>   pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server".

I´ve read other posts, which help on configurations options on the SQL Server side and the firewall side.

I can connect to the Database within the Visual studio, being able to browse one table of a data base using the tools of the visual studio.

BUT, when running the program I received the same error.

Does this problem has to be with the order in which things were installed? I mean, I installed first the Visual Studio and then the SQL Server.

Comment: re: Installation order, no it doesn't. Some things rely on this (Like installiung IIS after.Net) but for SQL, it's simply a matter of having the right components loaded. When you connect using Management Studio, what do you see in the "Server Name" field? `Manuel-PC`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my poor translation skills are correct, that's the generic "Couldn't connect" error which can mean anything from "You specified the host/port incorrectly" to "you provided incorrect credentials".

Your connection string doesn't seem to be correct to me - `.\` means local machine

Have a look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 and double-check the syntax of your connection string.

Comment: sorry misstype...error corrected, still the message error appears